# How to use Pseudo Code in a .xml file under res/layout folder? Android

Tags: java, android, xml, pseudocode, sgml

So I want to tell myself some things withing the .xml file using Pseudo code but when I do the // it enters it like a code so I can't really use it in there. Is there something I could do to make the code non readable like Pseudo Code? I'm doing this in an android application. Under the res/layout/(.xml file)   folder. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment in XML are like this

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

Notice that they can span on multiple lines

```
<!--
    This is a comment
    on multiple lines
-->
```

But they cannot be nested

```
<!-- This <!-- is a comment --> This is not -->
```

Also you cannot use them inside tags

```
<EditText <!--This is not valid--> android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
```

Comment: I tried that but then it like hides it from the android:id to all the way down I just want to use the code on the android:textSize line   <TextView
            
        android:text="invalid"    
        android:textSize="25dp" <!-- Comment -->
        android:id="@+id/tvResults"      
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />

Comment: @FernandoRamirez You cannot use them inside a tag, as the answer states.

Comment: @FernandoRamirez as i said you cannot use them inside a tag, if you want to comment an attribute in a widget tag you bring out of the tag and then comment it

Answer (score 0):

Comments in HTML & XML are like so:

```
<!-- this is a comment -->
```

See [On SGML and HTML: Comments](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.4) for more details.

---

Suggestion:

```
<!-- textSize: For the 'hearing impaired'. --> 
<TextView 
    android:text="invalid" 
    android:textSize="25dp" 
    android:id="@+id/tvResults" 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```